# Efficient approach for sorting names from file?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, python-3.x

I am tackling an objective that requires me to sort a list of names (> 10,000) from a file. What is an efficient approach in accomplishing this? Names could vary in char length and I do not have to worry about special chars or spaces.

At a very high level what steps should be taken? Example:
1) Read from file
2) Separate names into data structure. What structure would be best? List? Tree? Etc.
3) Sort. Quick Sort? Radix Sort? Etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck, or why wasn't this solution good enough?

Comment: I don't think sorting 10000 names is going to take very long.

Comment: Have you considered `sort`ing a `list`?

Comment: I am doing some pre-planning. I want use QuickSort for its easy implementation but was wondering if there is something more efficient for strings? Also, for a task like this, I was wondering if using something more complex than a List would be a better choice when loading in the data?

Comment: `sorted(file_object)`

Comment: Do it the easy way first.  Then figure out if you need to go implement quick sort and a more complex data structure.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will @Teepeemm. I just found this: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 1):

`List` data structure is good enough to use and choose algorithm based on table (i would use `merge sort` )

[image][image]

[image]